# Paypal adaptive payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

How can i implement payment with two receivers with PHP as a Webservice will be used in Mobile App?

User will pay from mobile app only  with his/her credentials.Payment should be done with Webservice(API's).

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/ or https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/ ? They have a lot of details on how to integrate from their README.md

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure on the integration to a Mobile App (depends what platform etc.). Are you set on an actual app? Or would you be ok with just creating a web app (ie. mobile responsive website)? I have a website, and then for my app, I just built a very mobile responsive site to facilitate as if you are in an app.

This is what I used to integrate into my website where I have my users paying each other, and they are allowed to send payments to two or more receivers as well. Andrew (the owner of the site/code below) is a genius and his code is so easy to use/implement. It is all PHP based.

https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/

And here I think is what you want directly referenced from PayPal developer site. What you are looking for is the Adaptive Payments "Pay" API call:

[https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APCallsHeadersAndPaymentTypes/)

```
Pay API: Transfers funds from a sender's PayPal account to one or more receivers' PayPal accounts (up to 6 receivers)
```